# Game communicates with MongoDB in the Editor but not in WebGL build

Tags: unity, c#, networking, databases, mongodb

I was trying to implement MongoDB in my Unity WebGL game and everything is working fine in the editor: I managed to insert and retrieve documents from my Mongo database with no issues.

Everything seemed perfect until I compiled the project and realized that my WebGL build won't communicate with my database at all!

I took a look at the console and I see this error:

> MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMap`1[[UserAccount, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

I have no clue what's happening. I tried compiling the project for Windows/Linux and I got the same error, then I changed API compatibility level to 4.x and it was working fine on the Windows build, but not on WebGL ( API compatibility level=4.x is checked for WebGL build!)

Can someone lend me a hand with that?

Comment: You need your app to connect to websocket/http server(Preferably node.js) which will then connect to mongodb. This will also add security to the app.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do here unfortunately **can not** work. The [MongoDB protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/) is based directly on TCP/IP. But a web application running in a web browser can not create raw TCP/IP connections. There is no API in JavaScript for doing that. The closest it gets are HTTP requests ("AJAX") and WebSockets (which are intentionally incompatible with regular sockets). A WebGL build *is* a JavaScript application, so if the JavaScript API can't do something, then Unity won't magically allow you to do it.

If you want to use a MongoDB database from your Unity application running in the browser, then you will have to use [a middleware which provides a REST API for MongoDB](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces.html) which you can then access from your game by using the [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) class.

Comment: that explains everything, it seems I have plenty of work ahead :(, thank you a lot for your help! you saved me!

Comment: @roseicollis Are you already committed to using MongoDB as your database? If you are looking for a document-oriented NoSQL database which offers a REST API out-of-the-box, then you might want to take a look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Comment: I'll take a look at that, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @roseicollis When this post answered your question, please accept it by clicking the checkmark-icon next to it.

Comment: For future reference, I faced the same problems myself, and implemented what Philipp suggested quite recently. I have written a short github repo that details how to connect Unity to a MongoDB Atlas VM [here](https://github.com/aowais2/MongoDBwUnity)